# what is the difference between the epoch time in java and sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I get a very different date when i use the date function of sqlite to convert an epoch time i stored using java calendar's getTimeMillis

```
`date(date_todo,'unixepoch')`  
`-1413-03-01`
```

the date_todo field gives `2017-03-01` with java Calendar

Also generating epoch time using the `%s` modifier gives a different value which has fewer digits.
    `strftime('%s','now')`
    `1485116265`

10 digits while uisng `Calendar.getTimeMillis` gives 13 digits

Comment: I'm gonna make a guess based on the information you supplied (hence not written as an actual answer). But it seems that SQLite uses epoch with seconds precision, whilst Java gives epoch with miliseconds precision Edit: my hunch is correct, https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html "the number of seconds since 1970"

Comment: thanks for your answer